# vkCreateWin32SurfaceKHR not writing to surface

Tags: graphics, vulkan

I'm trying to get a simple test of Vulkan working. I've been following the LunarG tutorials, but ran into the problem that `vkCreateWin32SurfaceKHR` seems to do nothing. Namely, `surface` is not being written to. The function `vkCreateWin32SurfaceKHR` returns 0, so it isn't reporting a failure. Any help is appreciated.

```
    // create window
    sdlWindow = SDL_CreateWindow(APP_SHORT_NAME, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, width, height, 0);
    struct SDL_SysWMinfo wmInfo;
    SDL_VERSION(&wmInfo.version);
    SDL_GetWindowWMInfo(sdlWindow, &wmInfo);
    hWnd = wmInfo.info.win.window;
    hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

    // create a surface attached to the window
    VkWin32SurfaceCreateInfoKHR surface_info = {};
    surface_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_WIN32_SURFACE_CREATE_INFO_KHR;
    surface_info.pNext = NULL;
    surface_info.hinstance = hInstance;
    surface_info.hwnd = hWnd;
    sanity(!vkCreateWin32SurfaceKHR(inst, &surface_info, NULL, &surface));
```

Comment: "*Namely, surface is not being written to.*" I don't see where you're writing to a surface.

Comment: Also try to enable the validation layers. If a function returns a valid error code then you also get a message by the validation layers hinting you at why the error occurred. The SDK even contains a special layer for swapchain validation.

Comment: @NicolBolas I should clarify what I mean by writing to `surface` is the last parameter to the function is an output parameter. The value in `&surface` should be overwritten.

Comment: @SaschaWillems I will have to look into the validation layers tonight, but I haven't gotten that far in the tutorial yet! :-)

Comment: @SaschaWillems Maybe I misunderstand your comment. The function is not returning an error code. It does not trigger my `sanity` assertion. It just blithely keeps running with an uninitialized surface. I wonder if I have to do something specifically to enable the Win32 platform extensions, but there is no mention of that in the tutorial.

Comment: Do you enable the extension when creating the instance? For your case you'd have to add the "VK_KHR_WIN32_SURFACE_EXTENSION_NAME" constant to the list of enabled extensions passed to the ppEnabledExtensionNames member of the VkInstanceCreateInfo.

Comment: @SaschaWillems That is probably it! I don't think that I am specifically requesting any extensions. Thanks, I can't wait to try that out. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sascha Willems correctly identified that I was not requesting the extensions necessary to create a surface. I changed my code to request extensions as shown below, and now everything works as expected.

```
    // create an instance
    vector<char*> enabledInstanceExtensions;
    enabledInstanceExtensions.push_back(VK_KHR_SURFACE_EXTENSION_NAME);
    enabledInstanceExtensions.push_back(VK_KHR_WIN32_SURFACE_EXTENSION_NAME);
#ifdef VALIDATE_VULKAN
    enabledInstanceExtensions.push_back("VK_EXT_debug_report");
#endif

    vector<char*> enabledInstanceLayers;
#ifdef VALIDATE_VULKAN
    enabledInstanceLayers.push_back("VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation");
#endif

    VkInstanceCreateInfo inst_info = {};
    inst_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
    inst_info.pNext = NULL;
    inst_info.flags = 0;
    inst_info.pApplicationInfo = &app_info;
    inst_info.enabledExtensionCount = (uint32_t)enabledInstanceExtensions.size();
    inst_info.ppEnabledExtensionNames = enabledInstanceExtensions.data();
    inst_info.enabledLayerCount = (uint32_t)enabledInstanceLayers.size();
    inst_info.ppEnabledLayerNames = enabledInstanceLayers.data();
    sanity(!vkCreateInstance(&inst_info, NULL, &instance));
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside what Joe added in his answer, I will also say that the call to **vkCreateWin32SurfaceKHR()** if provided invalid arguments does not fail and return **VK_SUCCESS**. I`m not sure about other platforms if this is still the case. 
When I say invalid arguments I am referring to the two most important **hinstance** and **hwnd** of the vulkan structure **VkWin32SurfaceCreateInfoKHR**.
So pay close attention to those two arguments, it tricked me few times.
Not sure tough why is returning VK_SUCCESS while providing invalid arguments, there may be some internal related things that god know why.